# How to calculate size of gtk4-rs widget with custom function

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4, gtk-rs

I have custom subclass of gtk::Box, I need to make it calculate width based on parent(50% for example) and height using aspect ratio that needs to be specified.

I tried implementing size_allocate using WidgetImpl, but when using println! inside of it nothing happened(I tried calling object.size_allocate but it is different function probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [gtk constraints](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Constraint.html)

Comment: How do I apply my constraint layout?

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that I need to set layout manager, thank you.